# In the sentence: "I went to school on Sunday afternoon." when it follows a day of the week, is the word "afternoon" an adjective/noun.....?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns, parts-of-speech

In the sentence: "I went to school on Monday afternoon." or "It was a beautiful Monday afternoon.....", is the word "afternoon" an adjective/noun.....?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Afternoon* is **always** a noun.

You can verify this by using a determiner of some sort (and omitting *Monday*):

> I went to school on **that** afternoon.
> It was **a** beautiful afternoon.

There is no reason that a word would change from being an adjective to a noun (or vice-versa) simply by the insertion of another word which doesn't actually change its meaning. *Afternoon* still refers to a period of time whether it follows something like *Monday* or not.

The same applies to *Monday.* In these sentences, *Monday* refers to a particular period of time within a week, just as it does when it's followed by *afternoon*:

> I went to school on that Monday.
> It was a Monday when...

There may be a question about which noun is **functioning** as an adjective in the phrase "Monday afternoon"; one of those nouns will be an attributive noun. Generally the attributive noun comes first ("window frame"; "porcelain bath") as there are very few cases in English where an adjective is post-positive. Something like "Part the first" is archaic enough to be obsolete; "Attorney General" is still current but hails from a past age.

In a [now deleted] comment, you stated that you are  asked to underline the adjectives and circle the nouns. There is no way of knowing what the expected answer is. *Monday* is a noun, but it functions as an adjective.

---

Just for completeness, we could consider a word like *red.* That's an adjective,

> a red apple

but it can be a noun — but in the case of a noun, it means "a particular shade of red" or "a particular red colour".

> I want my room painted **that** red.

Here, the **meaning** of the word *red* is changed depending on whether it's an adjective or a noun. That doesn't apply to *afternoon* or *Monday.*

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Well of course, if the question hadn't been closed, you could write an answer. However, I take it that you agree that neither is actually an *adjective.* If you indicate you would like to write an answer, I'll happily reopen the question.

Comment: I think "on Monday afternoon" is an extreme ellipsis for "on Monday, in the afternoon" and the construction is actually idiomatic. You could also conceivably have "in the afternoon Monday".